# /etc/network/interfaces file almost empty

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04, bridge

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server system where the interface em1 is bounded to a bridge:

```
ifconfig em1

em1       Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW c4:34:6b:ae:ea:a8
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:677380321 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:396179860 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000
          Bytes RX:839163556407 (839.1 GB)  TX bytes:372594438191 (372.5 GB)
          Interrupción:64 Memoria:fb800000-fbffffff

ifconfig br0

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW c4:34:6b:ae:ea:a8
          Direc. inet:10.128.3.64  Difus.:10.128.255.255  Másc:255.255.0.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::c634:6bff:feae:eaa8/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:147880064 errores:0 perdidos:2217 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:189723115 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0
          Bytes RX:797220818733 (797.2 GB)  TX bytes:225007583950 (225.0 GB)
```

The network is fine but I cannot find the configuration of either the interface or the bridge in the file /etc/network/interfaces whose content is this now (I configured both the interface and the bridge through interfaces file):

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I checked is there's some process related to Network Manager but I don't find it.

In addition, the content of the directory /etc/network is this:

```
ls /etc/network
if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d  interfaces     interfaces.1479200968  interfaces.1479201325  interfaces.1479203373  run
```

Not a single file in this directory has configuration of the interfaces.

When could I find the current configuration of the network?

Thank you very much

Comment: The interfaces file is supposed to source files in `interfaces.d/`, and that's typically where automatic configurations put interface data (as individual files for interfaces is easier to manage automatically). When you say that the `/etc/interfaces` file is "this now", do you mean that you filled it with information but now it has nothing? Also, what are the contents of `interfaces.1479200968`,  `interfaces.1479201325`, and  `interfaces.1479203373`? I suspect you'll probably find your configuration in there.

Comment: Yes,I filled interfaces file with the configuration but now for some reason it has the content I've put in my first message. The three files interfaces.* have the same content as interfaces that is "auto lo iface lo inet loopback"

Answer (score 1):

**This is normal** By default an Ubuntu desktop system uses[Network Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) to manage network connections automatically and dynamically. This does not require (and in fact typically requires there not be) entries detailing configuration of your physical interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces.

Sources:-

https://help.ubuntu.com/community

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Issues

Comment: Hi, as far as I know Network Manager is not running. There isn't any package related to Network Manager and there isn't any directories for Network Manager within /etc.

Comment: is your internet working now ?

Comment: Hi yes, internet works (it never failed) but my problem is that I cannot find the current network configuration (and my system doesn't run NetworkManager).